# Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix in menu_main.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-menu, android-attributes

I am new to android and am following this one tutorial pdf guide.
so far ive not found many unfixable errors.

except when i tried creating a folder in manifest of type menu and created menu_main.xml.

i get attribute is missing from the android name space prefix and a bunch other errors like unexpected text found in layout..
here is the code i pasted from the book. to the menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- Our add icon will have its own button -->
 <item android﹕id="@+id/action_add"
       android﹕icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android﹕title="@string/action_add"
        app﹕showAsAction="ifRoom" /> 
</menu>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Our add icon will have its own button -->
    <item
        android﹕id="@+id/action_add"
        android﹕icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android﹕title="@string/action_add"
        app﹕showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was delete the colons and re-type them because the spacing between the android:something was a little out of normal.